# OpenGL colors above 1

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

While OpenGL colors are supposed to be between 0 and 1, I have found that if you set one of the RGB elements to numbers above 1, it will cause the entire RGB value to approach white. Is this undefinied behavior, or undocumented behavior, or documented but not well known behavior?

For example:

Green: 0,1,0

White: 1,1,1

approaches white: 0,500,0

The greater the value of one element, the more the entire RGB color approaches white.

In case this behaviour is isolated to a particular platform, I am using ES 2.0 on iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds to me like a driver bug (no clip of the input value) and that it affects the other channels due to a shortcut a developer took. Looks probably in code something like this

```
uint32_t packed_bgra = ((b*0xff) << 24) | ((g*0xff) << 16) | ((r*0xff) << 8) | (a*0xff);
```

I'd file a bug report.

Comment: I doubt it would pass iOS ES tests.